# in ffmpeg conversion..is that complasery to give $_server['document_root']?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Which one is correct??

```
exec("ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i ".$_FILES['FILE_PATH']['tmp_name']." ".$target_path);
```

or

```
exec($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i ". $_FILES['FILE_PATH']['tmp_name']." ".$target_path);
```

is that document root is needed?

Answer (score 1):

It just adds some path information, so it all depends on how you've installed ffmpeg, and where.

e.g. let's say that the document root is

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = '/home/sites/example.com/html';
```

Your second code example would then look like:

```
exec('/home/sites/example.com/html/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i /tmp/xyzabc123 /path/to/target');
```

If you haven't installed ffmpeg in that exact location on your server, then the exec will fail.

Comment: marc i installed ffmpeg in root folder i.e ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe .then 1 st one should work right

Comment: root folder of what? the site? the system?